# Run .bat in all subdirectories without getting stuck in a loop

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a Main folder named "Finals" that contains 40 subfolders (all folders have spaces in their name), I want to execute the following in each of the subfolder

```
mkdir Blank_Mockup\Option_1 Blank_Mockup\Option_2 Blank_Mockup\Option_3 Blank_Mockup\Option_4 Blank_Mockup\Option_5 Blank_Mockup\Option_6 Designed_Mockup\Option_1 Designed_Mockup\Option_2 Designed_Mockup\Option_3 Designed_Mockup\Option_4 Designed_Mockup\Option_5 Designed_Mockup\Option_6 Flat_File\Option_1 Flat_File\Option_2 Flat_File\Option_3 Flat_File\Option_4 Flat_File\Option_5 Flat_File\Option_6 Working_File\Option_1 Working_File\Option_2 Working_File\Option_3 Working_File\Option_4 Working_File\Option_5 Working_File\Option_6
```

The above creates the following folder structure:

```
|
├───Blank_Mockups
│   ├───Option 1
│   ├───Option 2
│   ├───Option 3
│   ├───Option 4
│   ├───Option 5
│   └───Option 6
|
├───Designed_Mockups
│   ├───Option 1
│   ├───Option 2
│   ├───Option 3
│   ├───Option 4
│   ├───Option 5
│   └───Option 6
```

What I'll like to do is run the above command in each of the 40 subfolders.
I tried the following using some of the answers from other posts here, but it get stuck in a loop where the command keeps executing in the newly created folder.

```
pushd "D:\Users\blend\OneDrive\Freelance\SwagMagic\Final"
for /f "Delims=" %%i in ('dir /ad /b') do (
    cd "%%i"
    mkdir Blank_Mockup\Option_1 Blank_Mockup\Option_2 Blank_Mockup\Option_3 Blank_Mockup\Option_4 Blank_Mockup\Option_5 Blank_Mockup\Option_6 Designed_Mockup\Option_1 Designed_Mockup\Option_2 Designed_Mockup\Option_3 Designed_Mockup\Option_4 Designed_Mockup\Option_5 Designed_Mockup\Option_6 Flat_File\Option_1 Flat_File\Option_2 Flat_File\Option_3 Flat_File\Option_4 Flat_File\Option_5 Flat_File\Option_6 Working_File\Option_1 Working_File\Option_2 Working_File\Option_3 Working_File\Option_4 Working_File\Option_5 Working_File\Option_6
)
popd
```

Comment: I am going to try to teach you how to fish here rather than giving you the answer.  For starters, dont `Echo off` and put `pause` commands after each iteration.  LOOK at what it is doing.  If you need to, add echo commands to see more of what is going on.  Look into `EnabledDelayedExpansion` and understand why batch is so stupid (and I love it).  I myself would solve this using `FOR /R` and I would use CALL :<LabelName> <params> with each returned result.  Then you can process and isolate bugs via function style rather than spaghetti block.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to go back ("up") to the parent directory in your loop with `cd ..`:

```
pushd "D:\Users\blend\OneDrive\Freelance\SwagMagic\Final"
for /f "Delims=" %%i in ('dir /ad /b') do (
    cd "%%i"
    mkdir Blank_Mockup\Option_1 Blank_Mockup\Option_2 Blank_Mockup\Option_3 Blank_Mockup\Option_4 Blank_Mockup\Option_5 Blank_Mockup\Option_6 Designed_Mockup\Option_1 Designed_Mockup\Option_2 Designed_Mockup\Option_3 Designed_Mockup\Option_4 Designed_Mockup\Option_5 Designed_Mockup\Option_6 Flat_File\Option_1 Flat_File\Option_2 Flat_File\Option_3 Flat_File\Option_4 Flat_File\Option_5 Flat_File\Option_6 Working_File\Option_1 Working_File\Option_2 Working_File\Option_3 Working_File\Option_4 Working_File\Option_5 Working_File\Option_6   
    cd ..
)
popd
```

**Explanation**

[*Technical corrections/niggles welcome.*]

- `dir /ad /b` returns a set of bare folder names e.g. `Folder 1`, `Folder 2`, `Folder 3` for the current directory (e.g. `Final`). Therefore, `%%i` will correspond to e.g. `Folder 1`, `Folder 2`, `Folder 3`, `Folder ...` in each loop iteration.
- When you call `cd %%i` in your loop, this is the same as calling e.g.:

  ```
  cd Folder 1
  ```

  or whatever the current value of `%%i` is. That is, you are [changing the directory](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) with `cd` by specifying only a folder name. This folder is assumed to be in the current directory you are working in.
- Starting in:

  ```
   D:\Users\blend\OneDrive\Freelance\SwagMagic\Final
  ```

  in your first loop, calling `cd Folder 1` is the same as calling e.g.:

  ```
   cd D:\Users\blend\OneDrive\Freelance\SwagMagic\Final\Folder 1
  ```
- In your second loop, however, the current directory is still:

  ```
  D:\Users\blend\OneDrive\Freelance\SwagMagic\Final\Folder 1
  ```

  from [changing the directory using cd](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) with `cd %%i`/`cd Folder 1` in your first loop. So calling `cd %%i` in your (second) loop is the same as calling `cd Folder 2` or calling e.g.:

  ```
   cd D:\Users\blend\OneDrive\Freelance\SwagMagic\Final\Folder 1\Folder 2
  ```

  But there probably is no

  ```
   D:\Users\blend\OneDrive\Freelance\SwagMagic\Final\Folder 1\Folder 2
  ```

  so you'll likely get an error.
- To remedy this, you can change the directory back to e.g.:

  ```
  D:\Users\blend\OneDrive\Freelance\SwagMagic\Final
  ```

  before executing the next loop and `cd %%i`. At the end of each loop, you can `cd` to a parent directory with `..`. So if the batch file is currently working in:

  ```
   D:\Users\blend\OneDrive\Freelance\SwagMagic\Final\Folder 1
  ```

  after the first loop, calling `cd ..` is the same as calling:

  ```
   cd D:\Users\blend\OneDrive\Freelance\SwagMagic\Final
  ```

  This means that the next call to `cd %%i` (e.g. `cd Folder 2`) should work correctly and be equivalent to e.g.:

  ```
   cd D:\Users\blend\OneDrive\Freelance\SwagMagic\Final\Folder 2
  ```